# Neo4JClient Cyper.Create Deprecated

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I have just started to explore Graph databases and Neo4jClient library for Neo4J. I am using Neo4JClient v1.1.0.11 downloaded from NuGet in Visual Studio. I want to create a Node in Neo4J and for that I am using this code (C#):

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "user", "pass");
client.Connect();
client.Cypher.Create();
```

But on Cypher.Create Intellisense shows that it is deprecated. My question is what is the alternate way of creating a Node? An example would be appreciated.

In this particular case I have a User that I want to create in the database. The class looks like:

```
public class User
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe only one overload on the `Create` method has been marked as obsolete - unless there is something I am not aware of. The following code should do what you need and does not show as being deprecated.

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "user", "pass");
client.Connect();

var user = new User
{
    // initialise properties
};

client.Cypher
 .Create("(u:User {user})")
 .WithParams(new { user = user })
 .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

There are a number of variations on this that will work but it should get you started.

As an aside, were you to use the first overload on the `Create` method you would indeed see it marked as deprecated. For example, this code

```
client.Cypher
    .Create("(u:User {0})", user)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

would give you the following warning in Visual Studio

> 'Neo4jClient.Cypher.ICypherFluentQuery.Create(string, params object[])' is obsolete: 'Use Create(string) with explicitly named params instead. For example, instead of Create("(c:Customer {0})", customer), use Create("(c:Customer {customer})").WithParams(new { customer }).'

Comment: There's discussion to be had about removing a lot of these legacy calls.

Comment: Yes @ChrisSkardon. Happy to be involved if it helps.

Comment: I think we'll probably look at it from the POV of this issue: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/issues/126